# Position Circle of the very left corner while stretching screen size - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I've a simple program, that shows red circle.

```
public void start(Stage stage) {      
  Circle circle = new Circle(30, 30, 30);
  circle.setFill(Color.RED);
  Pane pane = new Pane();
  pane.getChildren().add(circle);
  Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

  circle.centerXProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(scene.widthProperty(), 2));
  circle.centerYProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(scene.heightProperty(), 2));

  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.show();
}
```

How can I position my circle on specific corner (for instance, the top left) and make sure it stays there even if I resize program screen?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StackPane` and use `StackPane.setAlignment(node, position)` to set the node in the top left corner.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication279 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Circle circle = new Circle(30, 30, 30);
        circle.setFill(Color.RED);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(circle);
        StackPane.setAlignment(circle, Pos.TOP_LEFT);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For position in the left top corner center x and center y of the circle should be equal to circle radius. ( Plus small offset,  1 px,  for example, to show the circle without visual cutting of very top and left parts of the circle.)

For bottom right corner center x equals frame width minus  circle radius. and center y equals  frame height minus  circle radius.

Comment: Can you show me with code, please? Just started learning and not sure which command is related with element positioning.

Comment: Circle circle = new Circle(centerX, centerY, radius, fill);

Comment: By the way, from documentation: Note: if an application needs children to be kept aligned within a parent (centered, positioned at top-left, etc), it should use a StackPane instead.